# Change CMS page content in Magento (orders and returns footer link)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have been searching for hours for a solution to this.  I want to change the content of the footer link Orders and returns to just read " please contact us for your return authorization number, and our phone number.  I can't seem to find where this information resides.

**EDIT:** I would like to change the form that appears when the "Orders and Returns" link in the footer is clicked

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Order emails ? Or the confirmation page?

Comment: on any of the pages there are the links in the footer, one of the links is "Orders and Returns", I want to change the content, so instead of the form coming up, I want to have Contact us for your return authorization number.

Comment: Are you trying to change the description of a page that is link from the footer of your site? If this is what you are trying to do, then go to that page and look at the  title in your browser then go to the admin -> CMS -> Pages and look for that title

Comment: @R.S That was exactly what I needed to do.  If you post this as an answer I will mark it as correct.  Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the content of a page that is link from the footer of your site?

If this is what you are trying to do, then go to that page and look at the title in your browser then go to the admin -> CMS -> Pages and look for that title